# How can I sort a 2D array and keep track of the original indexes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have a 2D array called distance[][]

It holds my values in column 0:

Example:

```
{ 5
  7
  3
  9 }
```

It seems like a 1D array, however I've converted it into a 2D array in order to be able to keep track of my indexes.

The way I access my first value is distance[0][0].

My question is: how can I keep track of the original index positions if I were to sort my array. I was under the impression that I may need to create a corresponding list of numbers in ascending order which correspond with the position my of distance values.

What would I do after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use comparator. Consider below code -

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] a,int[] b){
        return a[0]-b[0];
    }
});
```

`arr` is your orginial 2d array, where first column contains the number to sorted and second column contains index

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a `Pair` class that holds the item and its corresponding index.Then, keep a list of this `Pair` classes int two different `list`s and than sort one of them.Since in java, you can use references without creating a copy object,this should be fairly easy.Now the sorted list will contain the values and its corresponding indices sorted according to the value and the unsorted list will have the `Pair` sin the order you entered them, that is ,sorted according to the index.